# IIS 7.5 gives 503 error after importing new configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, configuration, export

recently I had to move all my applications from a server machine (which is going to be dismissed) to another one. Both machines run Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5.

I exported the configuration of the SourceServer to the DestinationServer and I re-assigned the IP to point to the new server.

When I ping the site URL it gives me a positive response but when I try to access any website it gives back a 503 error (Service Unaivailable). I cannot find the solution to this problem, maybe there is something wrong with the configuration that I imported but I don't know what.

May sombody help please? Thanks

Comment: Usually this is due to an issue with the app pool configuration, but check the System event log for events in the relevant time frame and you should get a good clue as to the cause. Things to look for would be conflicts between applications sharing app pools or missing dependencies on the new server.

Comment: Is DestinationServer a fresh install? What was your exact step-by-step process for export/import? What type of web application is it?

Comment: Please supply as much additional information as possible, like: website logfiles (IIS W3SVC logs), configuration samples, detailed error descriptions and possibly events from the system Application Log, if any relevant.